# How to deal with `uninitialized constant` after deleting polymorphic ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

We have a model like this:

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true 
end
```

We’re getting `uninitialized constant PatientVital` after the model was deleted and table dropped. An action tries to iterate over all the notifiable records, and the ones with `notifiable_type: PatientVital` are now orphaned.

```
Notification.where(notifiable_type: 'PatientVital')
```

The data needs to persisted. Seems like a gotcha using ActiveRecord polymorphic. What's the best way to handle/prevent this when deleting a model who is a polymorphic type name?

Comment: You still want the records but they shouldn't tie to a model? It seems like an anti pattern. Can you explain further?

Comment: We should have moved the data before dropping the table.  I suppose we'll need to pull it from a backup. Wondered if there was a good way to avoiding this mistake in the future.  Probably some custom code checks on any migration that drops a table, check to see if it's possible `notifiable_type` for example.

Comment: You can still move the data. That can easily be done via a migration it is leaving the data in a polymorphic table that is the issue

Comment: @engineersmnky yes we will move the data.  Just wondering the best way to prevent this kind of issue in the future.  Better test coverage or pre-commit hook, but it seems complex.

Comment: What specifically are you doing with the record that is throwing the error, because just querying for those records using `where(notifiable_type: 'PatientVital')` shouldn't throw any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Notification.where(notifiable_type: PatientVital)` and your code will raise an error when you delete the class, so you can react earlier that you need to do something about the records with that class.